# upload canvas data to s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

Now since the amazon has enabled `CORS` I was wondering if this is possible.

Can the html `canvas` data (on client browser) be converted to a `something` and uploaded to s3 directly ?

I am sure I can make a `PUT` request to amazon but that requires a `File` .

I can get `base64` encoded image data or even a `Blob` but is there a way to save this as an image to `S3` from the client browser ?

Is there a way to convert `canvas` to `File` so that I can make a `PUT` request or a way that amazon understands `Blob` and saves it as an image ?

Comment: It is possible to do it. pretty long to explain here. But if anyone is interested i'll write it down.

Comment: I would love to know how you converted the `dataURL` to a blob that amazon recognizes.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah `   function canvasToBase64(canvas_id) {
        var base64 = ""
        try{
            base64 = document.getElementById(canvas_id).toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.8);
        }
        catch(e){
            // Fallback if jpeg conversion is not supported
            base64 = document.getElementById(canvas_id).toDataURL();
        }

        //remove the format type
        base64 = base64.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "");
        return base64;
    }
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old post method to upload data from browser to s3

http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html

then I have used this idea
[Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

and instead of normal `POST` there can be an xhr request with the formdata to amazon and you are done

Answer (score 22):

Here is a working example where you take a data URL from a canvas and upload it to S3:

```
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
var blobData = dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
var params = {Key: "file_name", ContentType: "image/jpeg", Body: blobData};
bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {});
```

`dataURItoBlob`:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jungli. You saved my life.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something dumb here, but where does `file.name` and `file.type` get defined? It feels like they should be a (hardcoded) string for filename and `"image/jpeg"` for ContentType?

Comment: I am assuming in this example that the site asks the user to upload an image, which gets dispalyed on canvas and somehow edited/manipulated, and the site just pushes it back to s3 under the same name/type

Comment: where did bucket.upload come from?

Answer (score 1):

I was researching this and not having much luck until I found this post: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1712#issuecomment-329542614

AWS has a utility that will decode base64 in their aws-sdk: AWS.util.base64.decode(image)

Simple solution, and worked for me.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob):

```js
canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
  if (blob === null) return;
  bucket.upload({
    Key: "where/the/file/goes.jpg"
    ContentType: "image/jpeg",
    Body: blob,
  }, (err, data) => {});
}, "image/jpeg");
```

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way to save canvas is to convert it to base64:

```
canvas.toDataURL();
```

or you can set image type via argument:

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
// etc
```

Also watch this lib: http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: The OP already said they were able to get the Base64-encoded data (and they are obviously aware of the `atob` function).

Comment: what do I do with `base64` ? I want it to be saved as a file at `s3`