# Can I convert an image FROM base64 to binary client side?

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

After manipulating an image using a canvas element and then getting the result via
    `canvasImg.toDataURL( "image/jpeg", 1.0 )`, 
is it possible to convert the result into a binary image file client-side? I am trying to avoid

1. a round trip to the server and
2. Sucking the server's RAM into a GD process.

The goal is to edit the image and get it onto s3 as a file without touching my server.

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990673/upload-canvas-data-to-s3 ?

Comment: Yes, it totally does. Well, once I found this too: `URL.createObjectURL().`
Thank you. Wish I could accept this as an answer because the title of that q doesn't match my search terms but it solves this problem.

Comment: Ah sure we're not here for the points

Comment: Sure. Other people just might be searching with my string. Which does contain the problem but with different words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Daniel C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1970775/daniel-c)'s comment led me to the solution (here at [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata#answer-5100158)).

The one extra thing I needed was `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`, which gave me a string handle to pass the file around.