# Why some browsers make Blob object empty? How to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, blob

I'm working with Ruby on Rails5, and using heroku hobby. Then I want to let users select, crop and upload the image from Javascript directly to Amazon s3 [like this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails).

I'm doing it with jQuery-file-upload and cropper.js.

The code below work properly in chrome on my MacBook Pro, however, when it comes to safari or safari on iOS, chrome on iOS, it makes empty file (but with proper name) on s3.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
    var fileInput    = $(elem);
    var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
    var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
    var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
    var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
    fileInput.after(barContainer);

    var lastData = null;
    submitButton.on('click', function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
      return false;
      });
     // get cropped data
     $('#crop_img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob){
        lastData.files[0] = new File([blob], lastData.files[0].name);
        lastData.originalFiles[0] = lastData.files[0];
        lastData.submit();
      })
   });

    fileInput.fileupload({
    fileInput:       fileInput,
    url:             form.data('url'),
    type:            'POST',
    autoUpload:       false,
    formData:         form.data('form-data'),
    paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
    dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
    replaceFileInput: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    // singleFileUploads: false,
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    sequentialUploads: true,
    limitMultiFileUploads:1,
    limitConcurrentUploads: 1,

    add: function(e, data){
      if (data.files && data.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('.preview').empty();
          $('.preview').append($('<img>').attr({// insert preview image
            src: e.target.result,
            id: "crop_img",
            title: data.files[0].name
          }));
          $('#crop_img').cropper() // initialize cropper on preview image
         };
       reader.readAsDataURL(data.files[0]);
       };

      lastData = data;
    },


    progressall: function (e, data) {
      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
    },

    start: function (e) {
      submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

      progressBar.
        css('background', 'black').
        css('display', 'block').
        css('width', '0%').
        text("Loading...");
    },

    done: function(e, data) {
      submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
      progressBar.text("Uploading done");

      // extract key and generate URL from response
      var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
      var url   = '//' + form.data('host') + '/' + key;

      // create hidden field
      var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
      form.append(input);

      //delete submit event which is false
      $('form').off('submit');
      //and submit again
      $('.directUpload').submit();
    },

    fail: function(e, data) {
      submitButton.prop('disabled', false);

      progressBar.
        css("background", "red").
        text("Upload Failed!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I think this is because these browsers don't support toBlob() method, then, according to [this article](https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor/issues/170), I included canvas-to-blob.min.js in my html file.

But still doesn't work.

I also tried the following code instead of using toBlob() method (according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990673/upload-canvas-data-to-s3)), it doesn't work either....

```js
//$('#crop_img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob){
       // lastData.files[0] = new File([blob], lastData.files[0].name);
        //lastData.originalFiles[0] = lastData.files[0];
        //lastData.submit();
 //     })
 
 //insetead of the code above, tried this...
      var canvas = $('#crop_img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
      var canvas_data = canvas.toDataURL();
      var blobData = dataURItoBlob(canvas_data);
      function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
         var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
         var array = [];
         for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
             array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
         }
         return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
     }
     lastData.files[0] = new File([blobData], lastData.files[0].name);
     lastData.originalFiles[0] = lastData.files[0];
     lastData.submit();
   });
```

I am totally at a loss.... Does anyone help me please...?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably send `canvasElement.toDataURL()` via AJAX to a Server Language like PHP, where you can `file_put_contents('tempfile.png', $dataURLajaxResult)`, then you will have a file you can send, regardless.

Comment: Thank you so mush for the answer!
Actually I'm working with Ruby on Rails, though is that same thing?
I want to directly send it to s3 because my server (heroku) takes too long to upload via RoR...
What I'm trying to do is this : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails